# C# & Javascript regex to keep only hyphens next to alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to figure out how to write a C# & Javascript regex to replace hyphens within a string but only keep the ones that are next to alphanumeric.  I am not an expert in regex's and need help composing one.  I have tried the following:

```
(^([a-z0-9])-)+ | (^-([a-z0-9]))+
```

C#:

```
string UpdatedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("- gomez-rodriguez - test1- -test2 -", @"(^([a-z0-9])-)+ | (^-([a-z0-9]))+", " ");
```

For example, if string is like

> "- gomez-rodriguez - test1- -test2 -",

I need the replaced string to look like

> "gomez-rodriguez test1- -test2".

On Javascript, I am using the replace function.

Comment: Code? Using Regex.Replace? What is your replacement pattern? Errors? Exceptions? Code?

Comment: Yes I am using regex.replace to replace stand alone hyphens with empty space.  I am not getting an error.  I am having difficulty composing the expression.  The following is the line of code I have: string UpdatedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("- gomez-rodriguez - test1- -test2 -", @"(^([a-z0-9])-)+ | (^-([a-z0-9]))+", " ");

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: I have managed to figure out how to remove stand alone hyphens within the string except the beginning and ending case where its starts with a hyphen & space and ends with a space & hyphen.  Regular expression so far: ([^a-zA-Z0-9])-+ | (-[^a-zA-Z0-9])+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
 *(?<!\w)-(?!\w) *
```

This will leave a space at the beginning or end of your string, though, so you can get rid of it with a `Trim()`:

```
string inputString = "- gomez-rodriguez - test1- -test2 -";
string pattern = @" *(?<!\w)-(?!\w) *";
string updatedString = Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern, " ").Trim();
```

[Regex101 In Action](https://regex101.com/r/qEFEkc/1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a regex summary like this one from Microsoft: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) **and** an online regex parser.

A Goolge search will return many good regex parsers.  With a parser you can enter some sample text and then your regular expression.  As you get to see the matches in real time it should really speed up development.

I know this isn't an answer to your specific question but hopefully it is a methodology you will find helpful in the future.

Comment: Thanks Shimeon, I have been using https://regex101.com/ which I found while doing Google search for a solution.